# Why when I run my code the panel opens but it never reaches the actionPerformed function

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, event-listener, 2048

[panel view of my 2048 game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXeTX.png)I am trying to make the 2048 game. I made the terminal version to check my game logic and everything seems to be working. Now I added a GameFrame and GamePanel class. My aim is to be able to click on the arrow keys to move the tiles to the desired direction. My current issue is that when running my code it never reaches my actionPerformed function. I am using a blocking queue to wait for the user to decide on their next move. When running my code the panel appears with two initial tiles (as it should) but when I click on any arrow nothing changes. With the print statement I can see that it does not reach the actionPerformed function but I do not understand why. In my understanding this function should be running every 75 milliseconds (which is my chosen DELAY) and I have setFocusable(true) so it should be listening to keyboard events I think. In another post, I read about a similar issue and it said to use addActionListener, but I am not sure where I should add it if that's what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated! I will add all of the GamePanel, GameFrame classes and the main:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {


    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int DELAY = 75;
    BlockingQueue<Boolean> queue;
    Timer timer;
    boolean running = false;
    Random random;
    Board grid;



    GamePanel(){

        random = new Random();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
        startGame();

    }


    public void startGame(){
        grid = new Board();
        grid.newTile();
        grid.newTile();
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();
        System.out.println("game started");
    }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        int tileSize = SCREEN_WIDTH / this.grid.SIZE; // Calculate tile size based on panel size and board size

        for (int row = 0; row < this.grid.SIZE; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < this.grid.SIZE; col++) {
                int x = col * tileSize;
                int y = row * tileSize;
                g2d.drawRect(x, y, tileSize, tileSize);
            }
}

        for (int row = 0; row < this.grid.SIZE; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < this.grid.SIZE; col++) {
                int x = col * tileSize;
                int y = row * tileSize;
                Tile tile = grid.board[row][col];
                if (tile != null) {
                    g2d.setColor(tile.getColor());
                    g2d.fillRect(x, y, tileSize, tileSize);
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(tile.getValue()), x + tileSize / 2, y + tileSize / 2);
            }
        }
    }
}

     @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try{
            boolean running = queue.take();
            System.out.println("I am in the try");
        if(running){
            System.out.println("running is true");
            grid.move();
            grid.newTile();
            if (!grid.gridHasSpace()) {
                //TODO Handle game over logic here 
                queue.put(false);
                }
        } 
        repaint();
    } catch (InterruptedException e1){
        //TODO
    }
    }



    public class MyKeyAdapter extends KeyAdapter{

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    grid.setDirection('L');
                    System.out.println("Left key pressed");
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    grid.setDirection('R');
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    grid.setDirection('U');
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    grid.setDirection('D');
                    break;
            }
            try {
                queue.put(true);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
}
}
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    
    GameFrame(){
        this.add(new GamePanel());
        this.setTitle("Game2048");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
    }
}
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Game2048 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {GameFrame gameFrame = new GameFrame();});
    }
```

Comment: I'd discourage the use of `KeyListener` in favour of [Key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: From the `BlockingQueue` JavaDocs *"Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available."* - this is going to block the Event Dispatching Thread, so no other event processing will be able to occur (ie won't respond to key inputs) so it will never unblock.  Personally, I think this is a bad approach and would instead simply have a state value which you can flip between the key handler and timer ... or, in this case, just have the key handler deal with it - not sure what benefit the `Timer` is providing you in this context

Answer (score 1):

From the [JavaDocs for `BlockQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take())

> E take()
> throws InterruptedException
>
> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, ***waiting if necessary until an element becomes available***.

(emphasis added by me)

In the context of your code, `take` will block the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing any further event processing from taking place (ie key or paint events).

In the available context, it doesn't really make sense.  Why use a `Timer` if all you're going to do is wait for the state to change?  Why not simply have the key handler trigger a method when it's triggered instead?

I'd also discourage the use of `KeyListener`, if for no other reason then all the focus related issues it creates, which has been solved by the [Keybindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

This will also allow you to decouple the action from the source/trigger and allow you to re-use the logic. This could mean you could also add button controls to your UI as another means of user input and re-use the `Action`s for both the buttons and the key bindings.

As a conceptual example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new GamePanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GamePanel extends JPanel { //implements ActionListener {
        enum Direction {
            LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN;
        }

        static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
        static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
        private boolean running = false;
        private Random random;

        GamePanel() {
            random = new Random();
            this.setBackground(Color.white);
            //this.queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), Direction.LEFT);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), Direction.RIGHT);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), Direction.UP);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), Direction.DOWN);

            actionMap.put(Direction.LEFT, new GridAction('L'));
            actionMap.put(Direction.RIGHT, new GridAction('R'));
            actionMap.put(Direction.UP, new GridAction('U'));
            actionMap.put(Direction.UP, new GridAction('D'));

            startGame();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        }

        public void startGame() {
            running = true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            //int tileSize = SCREEN_WIDTH / this.grid.SIZE; // Calculate tile size based on panel size and board size
            //
            //for (int row = 0; row < this.grid.SIZE; row++) {
            //    for (int col = 0; col < this.grid.SIZE; col++) {
            //        int x = col * tileSize;
            //        int y = row * tileSize;
            //        g2d.drawRect(x, y, tileSize, tileSize);
            //    }
            //}
            //
            //for (int row = 0; row < this.grid.SIZE; row++) {
            //    for (int col = 0; col < this.grid.SIZE; col++) {
            //        int x = col * tileSize;
            //        int y = row * tileSize;
            //        Tile tile = grid.board[row][col];
            //        if (tile != null) {
            //            g2d.setColor(tile.getColor());
            //            g2d.fillRect(x, y, tileSize, tileSize);
            //            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            //            g2d.drawString(String.valueOf(tile.getValue()), x + tileSize / 2, y + tileSize / 2);
            //        }
            //    }
            //}
        }

        protected void directionDidChange(char direction) {
            if (!running) {
                return;
            }
            //grid.setDirection(direction);
            // Do what ever other processing your need to do
            repaint();
        }

        protected class GridAction extends AbstractAction {
            // I'd use a enum for this purpose, but that's me
            private char direction;

            public GridAction(char action) {
                this.direction = action;
            }

            public char getDirection() {
                return direction;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                directionDidChange(getDirection());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need the `Timer` to perform different actions based on the current state, then I'd make use of `Set` to track which keys are currently been pressed.  This will require you to track press/release states, so it does increase the complexity some. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125578/gradually-accelerate-sprite-on-key-pressed-gradually-decelerate-on-key-released/34126260#34126260)